# Call to Unknown Plugin Android

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

I am trying to write a plugin for my android phonegap application. I wrote the java class and the javascript items. When I was finished I took the java class file and added it to myEclipseProject/platforms/android/src/com/example/playSound/playSoundPlugin.java

I then opened up myEclipseProject/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml and added the following lines

```
<Feature name="playSound">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.example.playSound.playSoundPlugin" />
</Feature>
```

Whenever I try to call this plugin i get: Call to Unknown Plugin: playSoundPlugin

What am i missing? Please help. Thaks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I'm an idiot.  tag should be all lower case!! hope this helps someone in the future.